# Implement Firefly algorithm for color data

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, firefly-mv

I have some color data with [LAB](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space)() values from which I already able to generate images in python. Now I have to optimize the cluster centers using firefly algorithm for the color data. But I am stuck on how to give input to the firefly algorithm like I have LAB values and images from LAB values. Can someone please guide me on the data preparing part, I am referring to python but if it is possible in other languages then please recommend. Thank you.

Comment: When I google "firefly algorithm python" there are a few implementations available. Will these fit your use case?

Comment: That is not helping me according to my implementation requirement.